# Is there a way to sort influxDb by a field value other than time?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm trying to sort results from influxdb query but I can't get it to sort by anything other than time.

this works

```
SELECT last("value") FROM "table" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "tag" ORDER BY "time" DESC
```

but this does not work

```
  SELECT last("value") FROM "table" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "tag" ORDER BY "value2" DESC
```

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since sorting is only possible for the **timestamp** and **tags**, you might think about using a tag instead of a field for value2. But beware that this is only reasonable if the content of the newly created tag is not too variable. Otherwise you might kill influxDB with too many timeseries. 
Details to be found here: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/

A different option could be to SELECT all data and to sort "manually" – in your code. But if that is reasonable depends on the usecase and the amount of data you get.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering by something else than 'time' is unfortunately not allowed at this time. Maybe in the future...

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3954